# How to edit shipping address after click order in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I want edit shipping address after create order on frontend in magento 1.

I used observer, it's ok, but i cann't set new shipping address

Ex: i want change firstname to "ABC"

```
$orderId = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getData('entity_id');
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->getShippingAddress()->addFirstname("Abd");
$order->save();
```

And i also try this code but it not working

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
$billingAddress = $quote->getBillingAddress();
$billingAddress
            ->setFirstName($defaultBilling->getFirstName())
            ->setCountryId($defaultBilling->getCountryId())
            ->setPostcode($defaultBilling->getPostCode());
$quote->save();
```

It's not work, please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try something like this:
`$order->setData('customer_firstname', 'abc');`  to set first name, and to set last name you can use: `$order->setData('customer_lastname', 'abc');`. I tested this code in observer for `sales_order_place_after` event and it works.

**SOLUTION:**

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();   
$order = $event->getOrder();   
$order->getShippingAddress()->setData('firstname', 'abcd');
```

Comment: thanks for answer but it not work for me

Comment: please try code from edit

Comment: i tryed, it's also not work :((

Comment: please try ```Mage::log(print_r($order->getShippingAddress()->getData(), true), null, 'system.log', true);``` and tell what shows in system.log

Comment: it show [firstname] => abcd, but in order details on backend, it not change

Comment: weird, i tested it and it works... could you tell what event do you use ?

Comment: i used "sales_order_place_after"

Comment: and "checkout_onepage_controller_success_action"

Comment: i also use sales_order_place_after. please in observer for that event paste this: ``` $event = $observer->getEvent();        
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $order->getShippingAddress()->setData('firstname', 'abcd');``` at the begining

Comment: And shipping address fields in admin->sales->orders should change

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, it work for me <3

Comment: glad to help! :D